# Is necessary to create an LiveDataObserver only for one action like this.?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I have the next segment of code, I would like to add unit test for the next button, one friend say "There is too much to create one live data observer only to test each function" .  The problem is that I have at least 10 buttons with deferents actions like intents, calculation, send data, etc. each button do different things, some represents actions, others represent events .

The image is only one of those. but the question is, how to make it testeable , I understand for testing I would need to create a method on the viewModel , and make a LiveData only to return to the view and register the observer in the fragment only to make the intent, for me it sounds like "walk around" . Why should I have an observer only for a Intent, if the view dont needs to "observe" nothing, only to notify to the view to do something.

Its similar for the other 10 buttons.  Really I need to create one liveData to be able to test each button ? To have one observer and return immediately to the view only to do those things sounds exaggerated . There is a better way to do it ?

```
   buttonContainer.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
        val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts(SCHEME, activity?.packageName, null)
        intent.data = uri
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

- 

```
// Each of those make one action, but to have an observer for each, don't sounds good, 
// why whould I need an observer only for one action , but if don't, I couldn't test it 
liveDataAction1.value = true
liveDataAction2.value = true
liveDataAction3.value = true
liveDataAction4.value = true
liveDataAction5.value = true
```

Comment: It is always better to paste code rather than adding image of code.

Comment: you want to write a unit test or UI test?

Comment: I want to write unit test in the viewModel

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having multiple `LiveData`s you could have one `LiveData<Consumable<Event>>`.

Consumable is just a pattern for making sure your events are consumed only once ([Read this for more information](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150))

Then define your `Event` as:

```
sealed class Event {
    class OpenDetail(id: Long): Event
    object OnSuccess(): Event
    ....
}
```

Then in your tests you just verify that calling method x, results in the according `Event` to be sent out.